# Wrong figure number with subcaption and \hrulefill

Tags: subfloats, ieeetran, subcaption

I am having trouble with `subfigures` in my `IEEEtran`/journal document class. I am using the `subcaption` package to use sub-figures, and want to use `\hrulefill` to separate figures from the text.

Somehow, `\hrulefill` and `subfigures` seems to conflict each other in a way, that the next figure after a `subfigure` with a `\hrulefill` will skip one figure number.

I trimmed this down to a MWE. If i comment out the `\hrulefill` in line 16, the figure numbers are correct. Also, if i don't use `subfigures` in this example, the figure numbers will be correct.

Is there perhaps just another way to get the horizontal line above/below the captions of my figures? One that doesn't destroy the figure counting?

```
\documentclass[journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{subcaption}                             % Subfigures
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{mwe}                                    % <- For dummy images
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!b]%
    \hrulefill
    \caption{Figure with subfigures. Has the number 1.}%
    \label{label1}%
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\columnwidth}%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\columnwidth}%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!b]%
    \hrulefill
    \caption{Figure C. Should have the number 2}%
    \label{label2}%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=100px]{example-image-c}%
\end{figure}%

\lipsum[1]

Check the labels: \autoref{label1} is correctly "`Figure 1"'. \autoref{label2} should be "`Figure 2"', but is "`Figure 3"'.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's odd:-)

I didn't trace exactly what happened there, but anyway it's more natural to use `\hrule` rather than `\hrulefill` in this context, and that has the advantage of working:-)

```
\documentclass[journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{subcaption}                             % Subfigures
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{mwe}                                    % <- For dummy images
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!b]%
    \hrule
    \caption{Figure with subfigures. Has the number 1.}%
    \label{label1}%

    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\columnwidth}%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\columnwidth}%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!b]%
    \hrule
    \caption{Figure C. Should have the number 2}%
    \label{label2}%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=100px]{example-image-c}%
\end{figure}%

\lipsum[1]

Check the labels: \autoref{label1} is correctly "`Figure 1"'. \autoref{label2} should be "`Figure 2"', but is "`Figure 3"'.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That advantage is clearly difficult to beat! :-D

Answer (score 2):

The `caption` package is not compatible with `IEEEtran` and so also `subcaption`. Indeed you have the following warning in the `.log` file:

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

You can use `subfig` instead, with the option `caption=false`.

Note also that captions to figures should be at the bottom in `IEEEtran`.

```
\documentclass[journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!b]
\hrulefill\par\medskip
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=0pt}

\centering
\hspace*{\fill}%
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hspace*{\fill}

\caption{Figure with subfigures. Has the number 1.}
\label{label1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!b]
\hrulefill\par\medskip

\centering
\includegraphics[width=100px]{example-image-c}

\caption{Figure C. Should have the number 2}
\label{label2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

Check the labels: \autoref{label1} is correctly "`Figure 1"'. 
\autoref{label2} should be "`Figure 2"', but is "`Figure 3"'.

\end{document}
```

[image]